# Angular 2+ Check if content is overlapping parent container

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to develop a calendar in Angular 2+.
This is the actual result:

[image]

My question: Is there a way to check if the content is overlapping the parent container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly get the height of the parent container and the height of the content. Then make a comparison, so if the content height is greater than the parent height you know its overflowing.

Otherwise you could simply prevent the over flow with CSS by setting the overflow property to scroll.

Comment: The simplest explanation tends to be the most accurate, thank you